# mobile browsers having issues loading up a html5 background video

Tags: html, reactjs, video, background, html5-video

I have a full background HTML5 video autoplaying on the website. Some iOS mobile devices with Safari seem to be having an issue loading the video up, although a majority of times, it's working fine.  It erroneously shows the following: 
[image]

My code is as follows:

```
const videoDisplay = () => {

    let isMobile = {
      iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
      },
      Android: function() {
          return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
      },
      BlackBerry: function() {
          return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
      },
      Opera: function() {
          return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
      },
      Windows: function() {
          return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/WPDesktop/i);
      },
      any: function() {
          return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
      }
    };

    if(isMobile.any()) {
      return (
        <div className="fullscreen-video-wrap">
          <video playsInline loop autoPlay muted poster="./media/landingpg_bg.jpg">
              <source src={require("./media/video.mp4")} type="video/mp4" />
              <source src={require("./media/video.webm")} type="video/webm" />
              <source src={require("./media/video.ogv")} type="video/ogg" />
              <img src={require("./media/landingpg_bg.jpg")} alt=""/>
              Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
          </video>            
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="fullscreen-video-wrap">
          <video playsInline loop autoPlay muted poster="./media/landingpg_bg.jpg">
              <source src={require("./media/video.mp4")} type="video/mp4" />
              <source src={require("./media/video.webm")} type="video/webm" />
              <source src={require("./media/video.ogv")} type="video/ogg" />
              <img src={require("./media/landingpg_bg.jpg")} alt=""/>
              Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
          </video>            
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="v-header">
      {videoDisplay()}
      <Modal isOpen={modal} setModal={setModal} setFinishModal={setFinishModal} />
      <FinishModal isOpen={finishModal} setFinishModal={setFinishModal}/>
      <div className="menu">
        <animated.img 
          className={`logo ${(modal || finishModal) && "invisible"}`}
          src={require("./media/Renterii_logo_w.png")} 
          alt="renterii logo"
          style={props}
        />
        <animated.div 
          className={`notify ${(modal || finishModal) && "invisible"}`}
          onClick={onClickHandler}
          style={props2}
        >
          RENT ITEMS
        </animated.div>
        <animated.div 
          className={`social-media ${(modal || finishModal) && "invisible"}`}
          style={props3}
        >
        </animated.div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

Computer browsers seem to be having no issues with the background video.  So far it's been working fine with Firefox, Chrome, and Samsung browsers on mobile devices as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with the ios mobile devices and solved it.

As mentioned here : [Creating Video for Safari on iPhone](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6): "HTTP servers hosting media files for iOS must support byte-range requests, which iOS uses to perform random access in media playback. (Byte-range support is also known as content-range or partial-range support.) Most, but not all, HTTP 1.1 servers already support byte-range requests."

So you must check whether your server uses byte-range caching or else reconfigure it (I did it with nginx).

PS: Another secondary reason for ios video incompatibility could be the incompatible codecs of each video. The following compression standards are supported:

-H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps. Note that B frames are not supported in the Baseline profile.
-MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile)
-AAC-LC audio, up to 48 kHz

Comment: I'm not a video format expert, but is this information `H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps. Note that B frames are not supported in the Baseline profile` still valid in 2019? The article seems to be from a while ago.

Comment: @Kevvv you might be right i think this article  [Video codecs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Video_codecs)  is more reliable as far as the codec compatibility is concerned.

Comment: Are you using Nginx to host your frontend of the website?

Comment: Also, does Nginx necessarily require Linux?

Comment: I use Nginx as a reverse-proxy to Apache Tomcat.Tomcat's primary role is to render my JavaServer Pages.  If you don't want to mess with server configuration, you could, manually in your code, set the 
appropriate headers of your response outputstream for your video( something like "Accept-Ranges" and "Content-Range" I think) .

Comment: Nginx doesn't necessarily require Linux. [nginx for windows](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html)